# the surface of revolution $S_C$ isometric to the warped product $C\times_a \Bbb{S}^1$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $H = \{(r,z)\mid r>0\}$ be the half plane,suppose $C\subset H$ is embedded 1 dimension submanifold.the surface of revolution deterimined by $C$ is the subset $S_C\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ given by $$S_C = \{(x,y,z)\mid (\sqrt{(x^2 + y^2)},z)\in C\}$$

The warped product is of $M_1\times_fM_2$ is product manifold with Riemannian metric $g_1\oplus f^2g_2$ where $g_i$ is Riemannian metric for manifold $M_i$.

Prove $S_C\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ with induced metric is isometric to the warped product $C\times_f\Bbb{S}^1$,where $f:C\to \Bbb{R}$ is defined to be $f(x,r) = r$ i.e. the distance to the z-axis.

My attempt,it's natural to consider the map $$\varphi:C\times_f\Bbb{S}^1\to S_C\\(x,r,z)\mapsto(rz,x)$$
where $z\in \Bbb{S}^1$.
If we can prove this is isometry then we are done,I have no idea how to show this.

Comment: Have you worked out explicitly what the induced metric on $S_C$ *is*?

Comment: Let $\gamma(t) = (a(t),b(t))$ be the smooth local parameterization of $C$,then $S_C$ has local parameterization $(t,\theta) \mapsto (a(t)\cos \theta , a(t) \sin \theta , b(t))$ then the pull back metric is the induced metric on $S_C$.

Comment: Similarily $C\times_f \Bbb{S}^1$ has local parametrization $(t,\theta) \mapsto (\cos \theta, \sin \theta , b(t))$ the pull back metric on $S_1$ is $d\theta ^2$,pull back metric on $C$ is $(a'(t)^2 + b'(t)^2) dt^2$,hence the warped product metric is $(a'(t)^2 + b'(t)^2)dt^2 + a(t)^2 d\theta ^2$

Comment: thank you professor @Ted Shifrin , I have worked it out, I think my solution is not very clear,is there better solution

Comment: It’s just fine, but you’re missing an $a(t)$ or two in the parametrization. It’s common to use an arclength parametrization of $C$ and then the formula is quite simple!